# Would an old laptop run with converter SATA to IDE?

Tags: hard-drive, dell-inspiron

I got an old Dell Inspiron 7000 [(specifications)](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/pcyc/specs.htm) but there was no hard drive in it. So I wonder is it possible to run Linux if I'll install [SATA Female to 44Pin 2.5 IDE Male HDD Adapter Converter](http://cgi.ebay.pl/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=160567493537#ht_2983wt_1041) connected with 500gb 2,5" HDD ?

Comment: Its unlikely the hdd would fit inside the laptop if you did this.  Why don't you just purchase an IDE hdd?

Comment: @Ramhound, I just can't find so low cost IDE HDD as converter. And, for me, It does not matter if it will fit or not.

Comment: How do you plan to mount the HDD with the sata adapter in place? What HDD do you plan to use?

Comment: I don't have enough of reputation to place here a normal image, so:
[holder](http://cs323728.userapi.com/v323728187/6a74/dojM_tQ4F8Q.jpg)
and [2,5" SATA seagate 500gb in it](http://cs323728.userapi.com/v323728187/6a7e/RihbV3j-obU.jpg)

Comment: @ChetanBhargava I think that the main problem isn't how to mount, but how to connect and if would it work ?

Comment: @Z37 I have my doubts about fitting the drive with the converter in the bay. I would look for compatible hard drive rather this retrofit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possibly **if** you have enough space in the laptop. Usually there is no extra space in the drive bay, so you would need to be creative with cabling.

It will add extra delays though. No matter how good the converter is, it is going to introduce some overhead. That might be offset  by using a more modern SATA disk compared to an ancient IDE disk, but that is an assumption on my part.

Comment: I don't care about aesthetic look. It just should work.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can use an adapter to convert SATA to IDE. Whether 2.5" IDE(what you have), or 3.5" IDE. If you don't mind it hanging from the laptop if it doesn't fit as designed, that's fine. Of course.

Make sure to get the right adapter, but they're cheap. So you could even get a few and different types and you may need to use M-F adapters to convert things.  I've never actually used an adapter that went from a 2.5" connector on a motherboard.. it should work. Make sure you know which side of the IDE is pin1 and which side has pins 41-44 (power).  You could post an answer when you've done it, with pictures to show what the adapter looked like.

A warning- [Is it possible to plug a 2.5" drive in wrongly and could I break it?](https://superuser.com/questions/554540/is-it-possible-to-plug-a-2-5-drive-in-wrongly-and-could-i-break-it/554541#554541)

A question worth watching - very related to your question. 
[Is there a cable that is 2.5" (44-pin) IDE on both ends, or an alternative to plug a SATA drive into an IDE laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/554551/is-there-a-cable-that-is-2-5-ide-on-both-sides-or-an-alternative-to-plug-a-sat)

It's certainly possible in theory. But I guess (at least if using the IDE-SATA adapter board, and i'm not sure what else you'd use), and if it doesn't fit and you need a cable, you would have an issue finding a 2.5" IDE cable.

I have an idea.. if you can't find a 2.5" IDE cable. I've no idea if this will work.  But no harm in trying.
Get 2*  2.5-3.5" adapter cables.  Take the 3.5" female ends and connect them with a 3.5" male both sides gender changer. Then you will have built yourself a 2.5" cable!
I'd say ignore the two molex connectors hanging off the cables. The laptop should send power down the 2.5" cable through pins 41-44 to your drive.  Presumably a SATA-IDE  adapter board if it's a 2.5" adapter board, takes power from the IDE end to power the hard drive, I guess that's how it'd work. That might work!

Comment: @Z37 make sure you get an adapter that you think is ok aesthetically and physically. some are like a card type, and some are like a cable type. you probably need a card type with a cable, or just a cable type. you could get both and see what you like.  they're cheap.  you may be a bit unlucky and get errors with one, then try the other or another, which is fine 'cos they're cheap.

Comment: @Z37 make sure you check my update, with the warning!