# Is there a cable that is 2.5" (44-pin) IDE on both ends, or an alternative to plug a SATA drive into an IDE laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I want to plug a 2.5" SATA HDD into a laptop with an internal IDE connector.

They could use this SATA-IDE adapter board pictured below.
The SATA HDD with the adapter won't fit into the bay, but let's say that's fine.
It's largely an aesthetic issue; it doesn't matter if there's an "extension" cable.

When using that SATA-IDE adapter attached to the HDD, they could attach a 2.5" cable F-F, then use a gender changer at the other end so it looks like the connector of an IDE hard drive.  That 2.5" male end end of the cable could then be plugged into the laptop's IDE port

But I don't know whether such a cable that is 2.5" at both ends exists.

Or are there alternative ways of plugging a 2.5" SATA drive into a 2.5" IDE connector?

[image]

Comment: I have an idea.. if you can't find a 2.5" IDE cable. I've no idea if this will work.  But no harm in trying.
Get 2*  2.5-3.5" adapter cables.  Take the 3.5" female ends and connect them with a 3.5" male both sides gender changer. Then you will have built yourself a 2.5" cable!
I'd say ignore the two molex connectors hanging off the cables. The laptop should send power down the 2.5" cable through pins 41-44 to your drive.  Presumably the SATA-IDE  adapter board takes power from the IDE end I guess that's how it works. That might work!

Comment: did you get to try this? I am interested as I have a similar situation with and old Gateway lappy.

Comment: @CarlB i've tried SATA-3.5" IDE. But there are adapters for SATA-2.5"/44pin IDE  http://www.amazon.co.uk/IDE-2-5-SATA-adapter-converter/dp/B0041SIFNG   http://www.waeplus.co.uk/item/266763/2.5-IDE-HDD-44-pin%3ESATA-22-pin?ref=gooad&gclid=CKm1-KugpLcCFe3LtAod80UAxw    as for which way they go i'm not sure.  Maybe no harm in trying a gender changer with it and seeing. But if you look at the pic I added with the SATA-3.5" IDE adapter, it has 2  SATA connectors to get 2 way.

Comment: @CarlB   Somebody on tomshardware http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/294449-32-sata-adapter-laptop suggested this http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1PU0FR1089    A tray that takes a sata drive and fits in the cd tray which is apparently PATA.

Comment: Note, my related post has been removed, but is  http://demo102.phpcaiji.com/article/ffefea-is-it-possible-to-plug-a-2-5-drive-in-wrongly-and-could-i-break-it.html  albeit without pictures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a cable that would work. So if aesthetics are truly no big deal, here you go.

**Added by barlop - This is 2.5" IDE both ends, despite the "Micro SATA Cables" brand name.  And it has 2 reviews, both by people that know what they're talking about, both lowest rating,  pointing out issues with it that they think are serious. One review mentions that the red painted side (denoting pin1) is on the wrong side (though i'd wonder how that makes a difference - and how one would determine what is the wrong side. Either side could be deemed pin1 and the painted strip ensures that it's not twisted). A criticism in a review is that pin 20 on it has not been removed so would have to be removed/bent, but that's doable , the procedure is " You clip the pin by using a small set of wire cutters or grabbing the pin with needle nose pliers and bend it back and forth until it breaks off preferably flush with the plastic so there is no way for it to make contact." as described in a post [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/panasonic/553415-5v-3-3v-hard-drive-issue-any-electronics-geeks.html)  +1 for the principle though!**

The cable is this product on amazon [Micro-SATA-Cables-44-Pin-Converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0055D7YLU)

You won't have to bother with further gender changers.

[image: 2.5]

> **EDIT: by Carl B added information**

There is a descriptive set up of pin 1 on the below diagram and a link to a potentialy better suited product here at cablesOnline.com [6" 44-Pin Female to Male IDE True Extension](http://www.cablesonline.com/644fetomaide.html)

> **Specifications:**
>
> •This Cable is used to extend 2.00mm, 44 pin Laptop Hard Drive cable
>
> •(1) 44 Pin 2.5" IDE Female 2.0mm Laptop Connector
>
> •(1) 44 Pin 2.5" IDE Male 2.0mm Laptop Connector
>
> •Length: 6 inches

Note the interweave of the ribbon on the female end. So a stright cable like the first example may not be proper and thus the poor reviews and performance of the product to include incorrect pin 1 and pin 2 along with pins 43 and 44 orientation. This possibly cased the drive damage the reviewers were talking about.

[image: Ribbon detail]

[image: Ribbon detail2]

[image: pin out]

> Edit: added pin out of 2.5 IDE ribbon (a google images classic) - original source apparently from http://www.unitechelectronics.com/whyisitso.htm

[image: pinout of ide ribbon]

Comment: +1  -- but the brand name "Micro-SATA" sure is confusing when combined with the connector description.  "SATA" combined with "IDE" sounds like an oxymoron or a bogus adapter cable.

Comment: I have verified on the picture that the cable is 2.5" IDE(44 pins or holes even on the female end). Good find.

Comment: @sawdust yeah though if there were a cable with SATA one end and IDE the other end, I wouldn't say it's bogus 'cos it could exist.

Comment: I got confused by the same thing. And the reviews seem quite bad too.

Comment: @CarlB looking at the site, there are 3 pics of the cable.. (now all in your answer too) http://i.stack.imgur.com/HHSXA.jpg  and http://i.stack.imgur.com/EbCwj.gif  and  http://i.stack.imgur.com/cZasu.jpg     Notice that in the first two, it looks like 4 pins aren't wired up.  And in the third it looks like they are.

Comment: @barlop - interesting observation, could be a optical anomaly due to lay out for the pic? Possibly?

Comment: or somehow a mistake in the pic like a wrong pic, the first two pics that is! the electronic spec you pictured doesn't suggest any wires are missing so agrees with the third pic. On another note, swapping pins 1,2 and 43,44 probably has something to do with GND but I doubt it has anything to do with which side of the cable has pin1(a strange criticism of the amazon cable in a review),as that wouldn't change.And in fact,swapping wires on the far sides of the cable as they have, is symmetrical and suggests to me it'd probably work both ways!

Comment: @barlop - I think you would just have to have the orientation correct on the mobo and drive as the 4 extra pins and holes on the 2.5 ide ribbon compared to the 40 hole/pin of a 3.5 ide is to supply 5v and 12v as well as ground. Put them wrong and you could have issues.

Comment: @barlop - added pinout diagram. Can see if that pin 1 and 2 are switched with 43 and 44 in orientation, you could be making a 2.5 inch brick. Credit of image to http://www.unitechelectronics.com/whyisitso.htm

Comment: @CarlB Yes agreed "orientation" matters a lot. Either side could be marked with a red stripe(hence one of the criticisms of the first cable about the red stripe being on the wrong side, as mentioned in that amazon review is strange).

Comment: @barlop - agreed. The reviewer may have inverted orientation either from board or drive when connecting. as there is no "key" on the plug or drive, you will have to know where pin 1,2 and 43,44 are on both devices. I imagine if you plug the ribbon into the board and lay the drive as if it were to be slid into it's regular spot, you could see the correct orientation then push the ribbon onto the drive pins.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7600/discussion-between-barlop-and-carl-b)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this much, but this might help. It's a SATA-IDE connector, but i think it goes 2 ways. SATA->IDE and IDE->SATA,  I don't know if one ever needs a gender changer for this.  The power connector on it is not to power the drive, it's to power the circuitry on the board.

You may need a 2.5"-3.5" cable WITH a gender changer, as 2.5-3.5" cables that i've seen are female both end and you need the end of the cable that goes into the laptop motherboard to be male. Also you'd be plugging the 3.5" end into an adapter and then from there using a sata cable to a hard drive.  That is different to the normal usage where the 3.5" goes to a MBRD, and the 2.5" to a drive. In this context, I'm not sure if you also have to be careful with which side is pin1 and whether pin1 is pin1 on both ends. (A good technical review of a 2.5" both sides cable in the other answer suggests the red stripe denoting pin1 might only apply to one end, but i'm not sure if that particular point is correct).

[image]
This guy demonstrating one, is plugging it into a 3.5" drive. So i'd expect devices that look like that to be 3.5" IDE, but adapting between 2.5" to 3.5" is a common thing, though I haven't done it in this context.

**and bear in mind you'd be going the other way completely, with the IDE side towards the motherboard, and with a SATA hard drive connected to this adapter with a SATA cable.  (I only point to that picture to demonstrate that it's a 3.5" adapter and how it is powered and what the power is and isn't for)**

[image]

Added
[image]

added-
any sata hdd or whatever hdd has to be powered itself e.g. from a computer's psu. the power supply going into the board just powers a chip on the board.

Comment: Something else to be aware of, 3.5 might use more power than 2.5in drives. Although I am not sure about this 100%.

Comment: @JustinGoldberg indeed the 3.5" ones(i.e. desktop sized ones), do use more power.(at least potentially). They take the 12V wire(yellow) in their power cable(As well as red), not just the 5V wire(red) the 2.5" drive has. This is never something one has to be worried about, because the connectors for 2.5" drives already have the yellow wire not in there. Drives can idle.  In theory one might ask which uses more power, a 2.5" drive maxed out , vs a 3.5" drive idling. I haven't tested it but I don't think it matters.U can test with a power monitor plug / electricity usage plug. That'll show watts